# Solve equation about infinite integral. Find out all solutions that exist

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

The equation of $x$ says:
$$\frac{1}{2(x-1)}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (x\arctan y)}{(1+y^2)^{x/2}(e^{y\pi}+1)}\,dy$$
I've tried using variable substitution $y=\tan\theta$, and it becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2(x-1)}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(\theta\cdot x)\sec^2\theta}{(\sec^2\theta)^{x/2}(1+e^{\pi\cdot\tan\theta})}d\theta$$
After that I got stuck. There may be another approach to solve this problem by introducing some kind of complex variable functions, but it seems really tough to deal with the exponential term. So can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I tried $\;t:=x\arctan y\;$ We get an integral with the nice limits $\;[0,\pi/2]\;$ but still pretty ugly...but perhaps you want to give it a try.

Comment: My crystall ball says:  `x= -2,-4,-6,-8,-10,....`

Comment: It is a bit unfair not to state that this problem is related to the location of the roots of the Riemann $\zeta$ function (a bit like asking *can you prove RH for me?*). To prove that there are no solutions for $x>1$ is not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer. The integral can be written as the imaginary part of

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(e^{\pi y}+1\right)(1-iy)^x}\,dy $$
and we may notice that assuming $x>1$
$$ \frac{1}{2(x-1)}=\text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2(1-iy)^x}\,dy $$
hence the given identity occurs at the values of $x>1$ such that
$$ \text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)}{(1-iy)^x}\,dy = 0\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)}{(1-iy)^x}\,dy\in\mathbb{R}$$
or 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{y}{(2n+1)^2+y^2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-iy)^x}-\frac{1}{(1+iy)^x}\right)\,dy\in\mathbb{R}, $$
but the computation of the residues of $\frac{y}{(2n+1)^2+y^2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-iy)^x}-\frac{1}{(1+iy)^x}\right)$ at $y=i$ and $y=(2n+1)i$ easily contradicts the previous line. This proves we have no solutions for $x>1$.